# A Python tkinter smiley face with buttons that change gestures

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Update:
I've managed to create functions for my code and a constructor. The only difficulty I've encountered is whenever I run my program, there's an error  `name 'SmileyFace' is not defined` when I believe I've defined it. I need help as to why `SmileyFace` isn't defined. Thanks

```
    from tkinter import *

class SmileyFace:
    def __init__(self,righteye,mouth):
                self.righteye=righteye
                self.mouth=mouth


    def smile(self):
            global righteye, mouth
            c.delete(righteye)
            righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = 'black')
            c.delete(mouth)
            mouth = c.create_arc(125, 225, 275, 275, start = 0, extent = -180, width = 5, fill = "white")

    def sad(self):
            global righteye, mouth
            c.delete(righteye)
            righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = "black")
            c.delete(mouth)
            mouth = c.create_arc(125, 250, 275, 300, start = 0, extent = 180, width = 5, fill = "white")

    def wink(self):
            global righteye, mouth
            c.delete(righteye)
            righteye = c.create_line(225, 140, 250, 165, 275, 140, width = 5, smooth = "true")
            c.delete(mouth)
            mouth = c.create_line(125, 250, 275, 250, width = 5)

    def grin(self):
            global righteye, mouth
            c.delete(righteye)
            righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = "black")
            c.delete(mouth)
            mouth = c.create_line(125, 250, 200, 250, 275, 215, width = 5, smooth = "true")

    def main():
        global c
        win = Tk()
        c = Canvas(win, width = 800, height = 800)
        c.pack()

        c.create_oval(100, 100, 350, 350, outline = "black", fill = "yellow")
        eye1 = c.create_oval(125, 125, 175, 175, fill = "black")
        eye2 = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = "black")
        mouth = c.create_line(125, 250, 275, 250, width = 5)

        Smiley = SmileyFace(righteye,mouth)

        Button(win,text='Smile',command=Smiley.smile).pack
        Button(win, text = "Sad", command = Smiley.sad).pack
        Button(win, text = "Wink", command = Smiley.wink).pack
        Button(win, text = "Grin", command = Smiley.grin).pack
        Button(win, text = "Quit", command = win.destroy).pack

    main()
```

Comment: "tips and suggestions" is off topic for stackoverflow. You need to ask about a very specific problem, and explain how the code you have produces a different result than what you want.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. I just wondered why the specific functions I've defined for the four gestures haven't managed to do anything. The code I've produced when running only displays the smileyface with the five buttons. When clicked the buttons don't change the current facial gesture, so for example the smileyface would not change once I clicked the wink button.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to say what you wrote in the comments. That's a specific problem we might be able to help with. Though, it would really help if you took the time to condense the code down to a [mcve]. Often, the act of doing that will help you solve the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> The only difficulty i've encountered is whenever i run my program,
>   there's an error name 'SmileyFace' is not defined ...

When I try to run it, after fixing the indentation problems, I get `NameError: name 'righteye' is not defined`.  After fixing that, nothing happens at all when I run it due to a lack of a `win.mainloop()` at the end.  After fixing that, I don't see any buttons due to calls to `.pack` instead of `.pack()`.  And so on.

You've structured this program poorly.  The `SmileyFace` constructor should have drawn the basic face and saved the right eye and mouth objects as properties instead of trying to deal with them as global variables.  Below, I take an even simpler approach which is to use *tags* to avoid properties and global variables alltogether:

```
from tkinter import *

class SmileyFace:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas

        canvas.create_oval(70, 70, 350, 350, fill='yellow')
        canvas.create_oval(125, 125, 175, 175, fill='black', tags='left')
        canvas.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill='black', tags='right')
        canvas.create_line(125, 250, 275, 250, width=5, tags='mouth')

    def smile(self):
        self.canvas.delete('right||mouth')
        self.canvas.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill='black', tags='right')
        self.canvas.create_arc(125, 225, 275, 275, extent=-180, width=5, fill='white', tags='mouth')

    def sad(self):
        self.canvas.delete('right||mouth')
        self.canvas.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill='black', tags='right')
        self.canvas.create_arc(125, 250, 275, 300, extent=180, width=5, fill='white', tags='mouth')

    def wink(self):
        self.canvas.delete('right||mouth')
        self.canvas.create_line(225, 140, 250, 165, 275, 140, width=5, smooth='true', tags='right')
        self.canvas.create_line(125, 250, 275, 250, width=5, tags='mouth')

    def grin(self):
        self.canvas.delete('right||mouth')
        self.canvas.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill='black', tags='right')
        self.canvas.create_line(125, 250, 200, 250, 275, 215, width=5, smooth='true', tags='mouth')

def main():
    win = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(win, width=800, height=800)
    canvas.pack()

    smiley = SmileyFace(canvas)

    Button(win, text='Smile', command=smiley.smile).pack()
    Button(win, text='Sad', command=smiley.sad).pack()
    Button(win, text='Wink', command=smiley.wink).pack()
    Button(win, text='Grin', command=smiley.grin).pack()
    Button(win, text='Quit', command=win.destroy).pack()

    win.mainloop()

main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use global variables for *righteye* and *mouth* when you've already created a class that holds them.  Use the class instead of globals.

You do have multiple formatting errors. You have to be careful of your white space in Python.  It's critical.

So, reflowing your white space, fixing some missing variable names, fixing your `pack()` calls, and utilizing the class for storage, I get the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

class SmileyFace:
    def __init__(self, righteye, mouth):
         self.righteye = righteye
         self.mouth = mouth

    def smile(self):
         c.delete(self.righteye)
         self.righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = 'black')
         c.delete(self.mouth)
         self.mouth = c.create_arc(125, 225, 275, 275, start = 0, extent = -180, width = 5, fill = "white")

    def sad(self):
         c.delete(self.righteye)
         self.righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = "black")
         c.delete(self.mouth)
         self.mouth = c.create_arc(125, 250, 275, 300, start = 0, extent = 180, width = 5, fill = "white")

    def wink(self):
         c.delete(self.righteye)
         self.righteye = c.create_line(225, 140, 250, 165, 275, 140, width = 5, smooth = "true")
         c.delete(self.mouth)
         self.mouth = c.create_line(125, 250, 275, 250, width = 5)

    def grin(self):
         c.delete(self.righteye)
         self.righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = "black")
         c.delete(self.mouth)
         self.mouth = c.create_line(125, 250, 200, 250, 275, 215, width = 5, smooth = "true")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        win = Tk()
        c = Canvas(win, width = 800, height = 800)
        c.pack()

        c.create_oval(80, 80, 350, 350, outline = "black", fill = "yellow")
        eye1 = c.create_oval(125, 125, 175, 175, fill = "black")
        righteye = c.create_oval(225, 125, 275, 175, fill = "black")
        mouth = c.create_line(125, 250, 275, 250, width = 5)

        Smiley = SmileyFace(righteye, mouth)

        Button(win, text = 'Smile',command = Smiley.smile).pack()
        Button(win, text = "sad", command = Smiley.sad).pack()
        Button(win, text = "Wink", command = Smiley.wink).pack()
        Button(win, text = "Grin", command = Smiley.grin).pack()
        Button(win, text = "Quit", command = win.destroy).pack()
```

There are always numerous ways to code something. Everyone has different opinions about what's the best way. What's most important is that it works and that you understand why it works.